# Removing specific files recursively using rm or something simple?

Tags: bash, rm, recursive

I have a root folder with a text file in it called pairs.txt.

Within that root folder are other folders with text files called pairs.txt in them.

Is there a simple way to remove them using `rm`?

I know that there I could use `find . -name 'pairs.txt' -exec rm {} \;` but I would like to know of other ways, perhaps using `*` or some other wildcard?

I tried using `rm -rf pairs.txt` but it seems to only remove the `pairs.txt` in the current directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bash 4+:

```
shopt -s globstar dotglob
rm -- **/pairs.txt
```

The `globstar` option makes `**` match any number of directory levels. The `dotglob` option makes it include directories whose name begins with `.` (dot files).

With ksh93, use `set -o globstar` instead of `shopt -s globstar`. To get the effect of `dotglob`, use `FIGNORE=`.

With zsh, use the second line directly. To include dot files, run `setopt glob_dots` first or make the second line `rm -- **/pairs.txt(D)`.

Note that bash's `**` follows symbolic links to directories. Ksh's and zsh's don't.

Comment: That would be the equivalent of `find -L . -name '.?*' -prune -o -name pairs.txt -exec rm {} +` though. That is, it doesn't follow hidden dirs, but follows symlinks. `bash` got it from `ksh93` which got it from `zsh`. `zsh` and `ksh93` don't have the issue with following symlinks.

Comment: Is there another solution that doesn't require setting some sort of global variable like globstar?

What I need to do is put this command in a makefile, and I was told by my boss that it'd be more portable if we didn't have to change the globstar option

Comment: @ishikun You already gave the more portable option in your question -- using find.

Answer (score -2):

`ls -1R / | grep -e "/pairs.txt$" | xargs rm`

Comment: That will break if something in the path contains whitespace - not advisable. Using `ls` is usually not good advice for this type of thing.

Comment: That will not work at all since `ls` only outputs file names, not paths. whitespaces (TAB, NL, SPC) are not the only problematic characters, quoting characters are as well.